# Cloud Firestore add document collection on an Updated document in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have 4 screens with data collections that takes informations from User and in first screen I set the collection firstly for the user data:

```
CollectionReference addIfUser = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('influencerUser');
  Future<void> createRecord() {
    return addIfUser
        .doc(InUser.email)
        .set({
      'firstname': InUser.firstname,
      'lastname':InUser.lastname,
      'email': InUser.email,
    })
```

this above instance creates the first document for the user.

```
CollectionReference addDescription = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('influencerUser');
  Future<void> createRecord() {
    return addDescription
        .doc(InUser.email)
        .update({
      'description': InUser.description,
    })
```

this above instance Update the existing document then the collection is updated with the new data from the Form.

now at this stage users can start to create posts, but these posts doesnt have to be updated, they have to be added one by one because in the list I am going to show these posts as a list of posts like instagram.

so I changed to:

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('influencerPost').add({
      "postimage": downloadPostImage,
      "postext": InUser.post,
      "description": InUser.description,
      'whatsapp': InUser.whatsapp,
      'facebook': InUser.facebook,
      'instagram': InUser.instagram,
      'youtube': InUser.youtube,
      'twitter': InUser.twitter,
      "avatarImage": widget.imageAvatar,
      'firstname': InUser.firstname,
      'lastname':InUser.lastname,
      'email': InUser.email,
      'blogAddress': InUser.blog,

    });
```

but obviuosly without the updated version, most of data are null
I could also create another Collection called "Posts" but in the list i need also to show the user data from user collection, and if I create another Collection User data are not retrieved without connecting the 2 collections.
I tried also to retrieve 2 collections is my screen with 2 StreamBuilder with snapshot1 and snapshot2 but the length of the list return error because the 2 collections dont match the same length.
I hope it is clear

Comment: I did not understood what is your end goal here, you are already updating the document in the last code block, what else do you want to add? a new document to a subcollection of `influencerUser`? Your description does not make it clear, please update it so we can understand what the issue is, also, if possible share a screenshot of your firestore structure, this will make it easier to visualize what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i am unable to understand your question

Comment: I edited the question hope it is clear now.

Comment: It's still confusing, specially the part after the last block of code, but from what I understood you want to link a `influencerPost` document to a specific `influencerUser` document, correct? Why don't you use the uid of that document instead of `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`? Those will already be in the `influencerUser` document and you can fetch it anytime you need.